mysql/mariadb JSON_VALID
Example given here at db-fiddle.
CREATE TABLE `oa24_json` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `appnum` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `oa_json` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`oa_json`)),
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci

The JSON I'm attempting to INSERT was validated at jqplay.org.
When I attempt to INSERT the JSON that was validated at jqplay.org, mysql/mariadb Error Code 4025 CONSTRAINT occurs (presumably it didn't pass the JSON_VALID test).
Escaping the embedded apostrophe characters within this JSON string works for this simple case:
SELECT JSON_VALID('{"response":{"numFound":7,"start":0,"docs":[
{
  "patentApplicationNumber":["16286064"],
  "applicationDeemedWithdrawnDate":"0000-12-30T05:00:00Z",
  "applicationStatusNumber":120,
  "inventionTitle":["INITIATING A FUNDS TRANSFER FROM A PLAYER\'S MOBILE DEVICE TO A CASINO WALLET THAT REQUIRES HUMAN VALIDATION OF THE PLAYER\'S IDENTITY"]
}]}}') AS 'Valid ?';

However, it does not work for the actual (lengthy) data given at the db-fiddle example that has 107 embedded apostrophes. So my question is: What else I missing to make this valid JSON acceptable to JSON_VALID?
N.B. For the data given at the db-fiddle, I only escaped the apostrophes contained within the JSON strings; the other escaped characters (e.g., \n, \") within the JSON strings were programmatically generated by the United States Patent and Trademark Office, (USPTO).

It's almost certainly an escaping problem.  You'll probably have to write a small script to do the proper escaping.  Are you doing this from code?

Tim: Yes, I am attempting to programmatically generate INSERT statements after downloading the JSON from the USPTO using their API. Their JSON is valid; I just can't get it past jason_valid.

The JSON itself may be valid, but ALL strings being embedded into an SQL query have to be escaped, and that's your responsibility.  That's not a JSON issue, it's a generic SQL issue.  If you're using a database connector, it probably has quoting abilities.

Tim: I tried SELECT JSON_QUOTE('')  and got mysql Error Code 1064 because the apostrophes in the function invocation conflicts with the apostrophes in the JSON data! This is the mobius strip of quotes!

Quoting and escaping should not be an issue if you use prepared statements with parameters.

Barmar has provided the correct answer.

The JSON string contains character which needs to be escaped first.
Alternatives:
User variable
MariaDB [(none)]> set @my_json:='{"response":{"numFound":7,"start":0,"docs":[ { "patentApplicationNumber":["16286064"], "applicationDeemedWithdrawnDate":"0000-12-30T05:00:00Z", "applicationStatusNumber":120, "inventionTitle":["INITIATING A FUNDS TRANSFER FROM A PLAYER\'S MOBILE DEVICE TO A CASINO WALLET THAT REQUIRES HUMAN VALIDATION OF THE PLAYER\'S IDENTITY"] }]}}';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> execute immediate("SELECT JSON_VALID(?) AS 'Valid ?'") using @my_json;
+---------+
| Valid ? |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+

MariaDB [(none)]> select json_valid(@my_json) as 'Valid ?';
+---------+
| Valid ? |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+

Use binary protocol
If you use a client connector like PHP/Python, the connector itself will handle escaping when using prepare/execute (binary protocol), e.g. in Python:
import mariadb

my_json= '{"response":{"numFound":7,"start":0,"docs":[ { "patentApplicationNumber":["16286064"], "applicationDeemedWithdrawnDate":"0000-12-30T05:00:00Z", "applicationStatusNumber":120, "inventionTitle":["INITIATING A FUNDS TRANSFER FROM A PLAYER\'S MOBILE DEVICE TO A CASINO WALLET THAT REQUIRES HUMAN VALIDATION OF THE PLAYER\'S IDENTITY"] }]}}'

connection= mariadb.connect()
cursor=connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT JSON_VALID(?) AS 'Valid ?'", (my_json,))
print(cursor.fetchone())
cursor.close()
connection.close()

